# stuck on a echelon form row reduction question

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations

How do I row-reduce this augmented matrix?

$$
  \left[\begin{array}{rrr|r}
    1 & 2 & -1 & -3 \\
    3 & 5 & k & -4 \\
    9 & k+13 & 6 & 9
  \end{array}\right]
$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: In particular, the question seems pretty straightforward and we would like to know what have you tried and where are you stuck in row - reducing the matrix?

Comment: I just don't understand row reduction in general. especially for an augmented matrix. I'm new to the subject and I just need a good explanation of the process. or even a link to one.

Comment: Well, to start with, the row reduction is same as solving a system of linear equations (for unknowns) by eliminating unknowns one by one. If you look at any basic linear algebra book, you will understand how it works. Or, just "Google it!" Probably, the first few results should be sufficient for understanding the method.

Comment: Effectively a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2478252/265466, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1396595/265466, both of which you can find in the handy list of related questions at right, and many others.